# Float element without explicitly setting width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a container which contains 2 divs floated left. The div on the right always breaks to the next line because I have text in the div that is too long. I want the text to be displayed the right of the div. I want to avoid explicitly setting the width of the paragraph or the div it is in.

```
.container {
    height: 300px; 
    width: 260px; 
    background: #CCC;
}

.inner-container {
    width:100px;
    height:200px; 
    background:red;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

<div class="container">
<div class="left">
    <div class="inner-container">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <p>I want this to sit to the right of the red box without explicitly setting the width.
    </p>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/go3ugkr0/

Comment: why aren't you assigning width of the `left` to be `50%`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [**Flexible Boxes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) model which is a new layout-mode made to improve upon the standard box model by replacing the `float:` property.

For browser compatibility reasons using ***Flexible Boxes*** consult this - [**Compatibility Chart**](http://caniuse.com/)

I used HTML5 semantic tags (section, figure, article) in the example code below to add clarity and "definitive" meaning to your page content, increasing SEO.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x5g60nt2/1/)

Screenshot:

[image]

//HTML (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <figure>
            <div>Inner</div>
        </figure>
        <article>
            <p>I want this to sit to the right of the red box without explicitly setting the width.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS (index.css)

```
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
}
section{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 260px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #5c5c5c;
}
figure{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 !important;
    background: #ccc;
}
figure>div{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;    
    background: #ECF0F1;
    color: #5c5c5c;
    margin: 5px;
}
article{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
p{
    margin: 5px;
    color: #ECF0F1;
}
```

Comment: this example would be much better if it explained how and why it worked (why flex-box, how do the values achieve the effect etc.); and also cut everything apart from the bits that answer the question (for example, we don'y need to see boilerplate html and css - it clutters the answer and makes it harder to see which bits solve the problem)

Comment: @ToniLeigh I'll update it with comments to better explain it.

Comment: @ToniLeigh yea I agree with you in terms of just cutting apart the bits that answer the question for clarity, and I usually do that, however, I changed the HTML structure completely using semantic tags (HTML5) so for this instance I listed the entire source.

Comment: Ironically, I am creating this for a demo to explain how flexbox is useful in solving this problem, so I was just looking for the best non-flex solution. I should have explained that I also do not want to use flexbox for the solution.

Comment: @socketman I just posted another answer, this one relating how to do it without "flexbox".

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to float over text and for the text to flow around it (which is actually exactly what the float property is for), then you need to put the floated element within the text and float it, like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
    </div>
    <p>I want this to sit to the right of the red box without explicitly setting the width.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inner-container {
    float: left;
}
```

[See an example here](https://jsfiddle.net/go3ugkr0/13/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the "non-flexbox" solution you were asking for, from my other answer using "flexbox".

---

[Here is the **JSFiddle** Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g124azj0/)

Screenshot:

[image]

---

//HTML (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <figure>
            <div>Inner</div>
        </figure>
        <article>
            <p>I want this to sit to the right of the red box without explicitly setting the width.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS (index.css)

```
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
}
section{
    width: 260px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #5c5c5c;
}
figure{
    width:100px;
    height:200px; 
    margin: 0 !important;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
}
figure>div{
    background: #ECF0F1;
    color: #5c5c5c;
    margin: 5px;
}
p{
    margin: 0;
    color: #ECF0F1;
}
```